# Python argparse - user defined Action with 'store_true' behavoiur

Tags: python, argparse

Hi I suppose that i have parser argument which cannot pass any value, for example:

```
parser.add_argument('-s', '--staged', action=FooAction)
```

And my user defined action:

```
class FooAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print("action")
```

When i trying call this without any values:

```
python my_script -s
```

I receive this error message:

```
test.py: error: argument -s/--staged: expected one argument
```

I know that i can add action 'store_true' to my argument, but in this solution i cannot redirect execution of this argument to my defined action class.

Is someone know how to modify FooAction to achieve 'store_true" action behaviour?

## edit

class Fooaction with set nargs=0:

```
class FooAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=0, **kwargs):
        super(FooAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print("action")
```

Comment: Did you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/argparse.py#L900)?

Comment: Default `nargs` is `None`, which means expect one argument.  Look at the definition for the `store_true` or `store_const` subclass,  I believe it sets `nargs=0`.

Comment: `_StoreConstAction` class is not public, but `store_true` actions do this by init the `argparse.Action` with `nargs=0`. So, just do the same.

Comment: Ok guys, even if i set nargs=0 and/or const=True, it dispaly the same error message

Comment: Where do you set `nargs=0`.  I think you need to show more of your code.

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import argparse

class FooAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print("action")
        print(self)
        print(parser, namespace, values, option_string)
        
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s', '--staged', action=FooAction, nargs=0)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

sample run:

```
1151:~/mypy$ python3 stack56348020.py -s
action
FooAction(option_strings=['-s', '--staged'], dest='staged', nargs=0, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
ArgumentParser(prog='stack56348020.py', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True) Namespace(staged=None) [] -s
Namespace(staged=None)
```

Using your `init`

```
import argparse

class FooAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=0, **kwargs):
        super(FooAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs=nargs, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print("action")
        print(parser, namespace, values, option_string)
        
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
a1 = parser.add_argument('-s', '--staged', action=FooAction)
print(a1)   # display the action object and most of its parameters
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

1208:~/mypy$ python3 stack56348020.py -s
FooAction(option_strings=['-s', '--staged'], dest='staged', nargs=0, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
action
ArgumentParser(prog='stack56348020.py', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True) Namespace(staged=None) [] -s
Namespace(staged=None)
```

`add_argument` returns the Action object it created.  We usually ignore it, but saving it to a reference, and printing it can be handy during debugging.

Even though the Action subclasses are marked as 'private' (with `_`) it's a good idea to look at their code to see how they customize the base class.  `Action` class by itself doesn't do much.  The default action uses `_StoreAction`.  Store True/False subclass `_StoreConst`.  `_HelpAction` is the only one that does not store some sort of value in the `namespace`; and it does a system exit.

Comment: Setting `nargs` as you do in the `__init__` works for me as well.